# Checking conditions of 2 dimensional table

Tags: vector, condition, table

I have a 2 dimensional table and I would like to test if for each vector, x^2 + y^2 > 5.

vector is an element (x.y) of the table.

Is it possible to manipulate the elements of a table this way?

```
vectors[n_] := Table[RandomInteger[10],n,2]
check[vector_] := if[x^2 + y^2 > 5, k++]
```

Comment: You can use `Counts`-like functions: `CountsBy[vectors[2],Apply[#1^2+#2^2>5&]]`

Comment: Mathematica commands begin with an intial uppercase letter; so it is `If` and not `if`.

Comment: A simple "Count" will do: `Count[vectors[5], x_ /; x . x > 5]`

Answer (score 3):

```
test = vectors[5]
(* {{1, 4}, {0, 7}, {0, 0}, {8, 6}, {0, 4}} *)

Greater[Total[#^2], 5] & /@ test
(* {True, True, False, True, True} *)

CountsBy[test, Greater[Total[#^2], 5] &]
(* <|True -> 4, False -> 1|> *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy`:

```
test={{1, 4}, {0, 7}, {0, 0}, {8, 6}, {0, 4}}; 
GroupBy[test, Greater[Norm[#]^2, 5] &, Length]
(*<|True -> 4, False -> 1|>*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[n,vecs];
n = 5;
vecs = RandomInteger[10, {n, 2}]
AllTrue[vecs, #[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 > 5 &]
```